# Prove $||\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2 - y|| \leq ||x_1 - y||$

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

Assume we have have $3$ points $x_1, x_2$ and $y$ and $||x_1-y||=||x_2-y||$. How do we prove that the distance between $y$ and the convex combination of $x_1$ and $x_2$ is smaller than that between $x_1$ and $y$?

Comment: Any information about $x_2$ in relation to $x_1$ or $y$?

Comment: Sorry, missed one condition. See the edited version above.

Comment: @Cancan $0\le \lambda\le 1$ ? Also consider [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1283531/233398)

Comment: For some intuition, try thinking of the line between $x_1$ and $x_2$ as given by $L(\lambda)=\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2$. With the condition that $\| x_1-y\|=\|x_2-y\|$, you hopefully can see how to work through it intuitively, then rigorously.

Comment: @Clayton Thanks. It is very clear intuitively, but I have problem of proving it rigorously, which is why I want to see if there is any neat approach. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$,
$$||\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 - y||  = ||\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 - (\lambda + (1-\lambda))y||$$$$\leq ||\lambda x_1 - \lambda y|| + ||(1-\lambda)x_2 - (1-\lambda)y||$$$$ = \lambda||x_1 - y|| + (1-\lambda)||x_2 - y||$$$$ = \lambda||x_1 - y|| + (1-\lambda)||x_1 - y|| = ||x_1 - y||$$

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide a solution only for an inner product space $H$. Let $a=x_1-y$ and $b=x_2-y$. Then $\|a\|=\|b\|$. WLOG, set $\|a\|=\|b\|=1$ and hence $(a,b)\le 1$. If $(a,b)=1$, then $a=b$. If $(a,b)<1$, then for $\lambda\in [0,1]$,
\begin{eqnarray}
f(\lambda)&=&\|\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2-y\|^2\\
&=&\|\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b\|^2\\
&=&\lambda^2+(1-\lambda)^2+2\lambda(1-\lambda)(a,b)\\
&=&2\lambda^2(1-(a,b))-2\lambda(1-(a,b))+1\\
&=&2(1-(a,b))(\lambda^2-\lambda)+1
\end{eqnarray}
reaches the minimum $\frac{1}{4}\|a-b\|^2$ at $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$. So $f(\lambda)$ reaches the maximum at either $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$. Note $f(0)=f(1)=\|a\|=\|b\|$ and hence $f(\lambda)\le |a|^2$ or
$$ \|\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2-y\|\le \|x_1-y\|. $$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the triangle inequality to
$
||\lambda(x_1-y)+(1-\lambda)(x_2-y)||$.